# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. Incorrect syntax near ')' when attempting using an inner select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen the error before for a different reason but how can I fix this?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XXX] ([ID], [aaa], [bbb], [ccc])
VALUES (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.S_SHIPPING_ID_SEQ, @aaa, @bbb, @ccc)
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`.  No `values` is needed:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XXX] ([ID], [aaa], [bbb], [ccc])
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.S_SHIPPING_ID_SEQ, @aaa, @bbb, @ccc;
```

Or, if you really like `VALUES`, use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XXX] ([ID], [aaa], [bbb], [ccc])
    VALUES (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.S_SHIPPING_ID_SEQ), @aaa, @bbb, @ccc);
```

And, actually, this should also work:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XXX] ([ID], [aaa], [bbb], [ccc])
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.S_SHIPPING_ID_SEQ, @aaa, @bbb, @ccc);
```

But why not just declare `ID` to be an identity and use:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XXX] ([aaa], [bbb], [ccc])
    VALUES (@aaa, @bbb, @ccc);
```